# In Clojure, can I optimize scans?

Tags: optimization, clojure, sequence, traversal

```
;; Suppose we want to compute the min and max of a collection.
;; Ideally there would be a way to tell Clojure that we want to perform
;; only one scan, which will theoretically save a little time  

;; First we define some data to test with
;; 10MM element lazy-seq
(def data (for [x (range 10000000)] (rand-int 100)))

;; Realize the lazy-seq 
(dorun data)

;; Here is the amount of time it takes to go through the data once
(time (apply min data))
==> "Elapsed time: 413.805 msecs"

;; Here is the time to calc min, max by explicitly scanning twice
(time (vector (apply min data) (apply max data)))
==> "Elapsed time: 836.239 msecs"

;; Shouldn't this be more efficient since it's going over the data once?
(time (apply (juxt min max) data))
==> "Elapsed time: 833.61 msecs"
```

Chuck, here are my results after using your solution:

```
test.core=> (def data (for [x (range 10000000)] (rand-int 100)))
#'test.core/data

test.core=> (dorun data)
nil

test.core=> (realized? data)
true

test.core=> (defn minmax1 [coll] (vector (apply min coll) (apply max coll)))    
#'test.core/minmax1

test.core=> (defn minmax2 [[x & xs]] (reduce (fn [[tiny big] n] [(min tiny n) (max big n)]) [x x] xs))    
#'test.core/minmax2

test.core=> (time (minmax1 data))
"Elapsed time: 806.161 msecs"
[0 99]

test.core=> (time (minmax2 data))
"Elapsed time: 6072.587 msecs"
[0 99]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't precisely going to answer your general question (i.e. how to scan Clojure data structures), but it is worth being aware that this kind of code is often going to be better suited to **specialised data structures / libraries** if you really care about performance.

e.g. using [core.matrix](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix) / [vectorz-clj](https://github.com/mikera/vectorz-clj) and a little bit of cheeky Java interop:

```
;; define the raw data
(def data (for [x (range 10000000)] (rand-int 100)))

;; convert to a Vectorz array
(def v (array :vectorz data))

(time (Vectorz/minValue v))
"Elapsed time: 18.974904 msecs"
0.0

(time (Vectorz/maxValue v))
"Elapsed time: 21.310835 msecs"
99.0
```

i.e. this is around **20-50x faster** than the original code given in the question.

I doubt you'll get remotely close to that with *any* code that depends on scanning over regular Clojure vectors, whether you do it in one pass or otherwise. Basically - use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 3):

The code executed by `juxt` is almost precisely equivalent to your hand-written version — `((juxt f g) x)` literally works out to `[(f x) (g x)]`. It doesn't do any clever optimizations for collections.

To do what you want, I think the easiest approach will be a simple fold over the collection:

```
(defn minmax [[x & xs]]
  (reduce 
    (fn [[tiny big] n] [(min tiny n) (max big n)]) 
    [x x]
    xs))
```

Comment: Hmmm so this actually seems (?) to be _slower_ by a slight amount?  I am a Clojure newbie so I'm prob doing something wrong.  On my machine, using the Criterium benchmark stuff, I get         Evaluation count : 60 in 60 samples of 1 calls.
             Execution time mean : 1.110520 sec
    Execution time std-deviation : 50.605153 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 1.062179 sec ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 1.194490 sec (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 8.893154 ns

Comment: @DerrickJohnson: I can't replicate your result. I just made a Criterium benchmark with both algorithms and the reduce version came out significantly faster than the juxt version (983.684131 ms mean execution time for reduce vs. 2.248065 sec for juxt).

Comment: I've added my results above, see what you think.

Comment: You should really benchmark with criterium https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium

Comment: I wouldn't be astonished to see your version be slower, Chuck: it does only one traversal, but it allocates and tears down many two-element vectors, which will probably be more expensive than simply re-traversing a list.

Comment: So with a transient vector, it should be a lot better.

Comment: Ok this is crazy. I hope one of the implementation experts will shed some light on it (@Michał Marczyk ?). I just did a reducer based implementation, which performs twice as fast using `criterium.core/quick-bench`, but worst using `criterium.core/bench`. Also OPs code performs best using `criterium.core/bench`, but worst using `criterium.core/quick-bench` (including comparision to @Chucks code without destructoring). It almost makes me doubt criterium.

Comment: @amalloy: I would not have been astonished to see that either, which is why I benchmarked it before posting to see whether that was a problem in reality. But now it looks like maybe the benchmark tricked me. That one did surprise me.